# How do I set before content permanently using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use

```
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
```

at shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/) to display a rating bar. I wonder how I can permanently set this using javascript. I tried something like

```
  $( ".rating span" ).click(function() {
    $(this).html('\2605');
  });
```

but this clearly doesn’t work and it only affects that element which was clicked than the set of elements before as well. How do it do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method below:

```js
$( ".rateThis span" ).click(function() {
    $('.rateThis').before().append('<i class="fa fa-star"></i>');
  });
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="rateThis">

<span>click here</span>

</div>
```

**Note:** This is just an example, study and adjust as needed.

Comment: This code gives me a solution to add a star. I guess I’ll have to figure out how to add stars all the way till that point where I had clicked. Thanks

Comment: Umm, never mind. I got it--has to use nextAll(). Thanks a lot. I’ll post my final code here as well for others.

Comment: Welcome. glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class without the pseduo :hover: and apply that class to your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

`$( ".rating span" ).trigger("click");`

and it will execute the trigger immediately.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Thanks to everyone for the answers. Here’s the final code that I used

```js
$( ".rating span" ).click(function() {
  var ratingBar = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  $('#' + ratingBar + ' span').text('☆');
  $(this).text('★');
  $(this).nextAll().text('★');
});
```

```css
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="rating" for="Food" id="0">
  <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
</span>
```